# Xamarin.Android Firestore not working. Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android

I installed the Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore (123.0.1.1) plugin with nuget, but the stream is closed and I can't add data to the Fierstore.

I added Xamain.Kotlin.StdLib(1.5.21), but I still get the same error in the application console.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
[Firestore] (23.0.1) [WriteStream]: (66ee636) Stream closed with status: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Panic! This is a bug!, cause=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
[Firestore]     at okio.ByteString.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
[Firestore]     at okio.ByteString.<clinit>(ByteString.kt:222)
[Firestore]     at okio.ByteString.encodeUtf8(Unknown Source:0)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2.<clinit>(Http2.java:56)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport.start(OkHttpClientTransport.java:514)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:33)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:33)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:258)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:65)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:200)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1827)
[Firestore]     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
[Firestore]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[Firestore]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[Firestore]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Have you got this error when you create a new project to test? Please check the example for Firestore. https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents

Comment: I have confirmed that Firestore works fine with the new project.
It does not work with existing projects. I will check if it might be due to compatibility with other plugins.
If anyone knows the cause, please let me know.

Comment: The information is too less for me that we could find what cause this issue. You could check with the new project with the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

We also encountered the similar issue and after doing the investigation we found that we had to migrate the package.json to PackageReference. In Visual studio we get the option when we selected the package.json file to migrate Package.json to PackageReference. Refer to this article. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6219

Comment: Configuration of our project was old, so I migrated it to PackageReference and it worked fine..!!
Thank you very much for your answer.